# Typescript - asserting imported object to class static property

Tags: node.js, typescript

Having these two files:

ErrorCodesEnum.ts:

```
export const ErrorCodesEnum =
{
    generic: {
        NOT_FOUND: 'NOT_FOUND',
    },
    //...

}
```

Main.js:

```
import {ErrorCodesEnum} from "../enum/ErrorCodesEnum";

export class ErrorFactory {
    public static CODES: ErrorCodesEnum; //error: see below.
}
```

I am getting following error in Main.js:
Public static property 'CODES' of exported class has or is using private name 'ErrorCodesEnum'.

Is there a way I can use some imported module in static class property?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `ErrorCodesEnum` as a type because it's not a type. You can reference its type using the `typeof` operator:

```
public static CODES: typeof ErrorCodesEnum;
```

Or if you're just trying to assign `ErrorCodesEnum` to `CODES`, just omit the type and set the value directly:

```
public static CODES = ErrorCodesEnum;
```

Comment: Many thanks. I actually misunderstood some fundamentals.